# Sort on sub document python bottle

Tags: python, mongodb, bottle

I'm running a bottle framework and MongoDB. In the dictionary below I need to sort the sub dicts after rank. Mongo don't support sort of the sub docs (unless I sort with $push) and I would prefer to do the sort by "rank" for the media array in python and the template.

an "entry":

```
{ 
"_id" :"...",
"author" : "...",
"body" : "...",
"date" : ...,
"media" : [
            {
                    "caption" : "Drone",
                    "rank" : "2",
                    "media_link" : "34.jpg"
            },
            {
                    "caption" : "Tea drinker",
                    "rank" : "1",
                    "media_link" : "87.jpg"
            },
            {

                    "caption" : "Daniele",
                    "rank" : "3",
                    "media_link" : "54.jpg"
            }
    ],

}
```

The template code where I would like to do a sort by rank.

```
%if ('media' in entry): 
%numMedia = len(entry['media']) 
%else:
%numMedia = 0               
%end


%for i in range(0, numMedia):
<td valign="top">
<img width='200' src='{{entries['media'][i]['media_link']}}'><br>
Media Caption: {{entries['media'][i]['caption']}}<br>
Rank: {{entries['media'][i]['rank']}}</td>
%end
```

I've tried several different approaches but can't get it to work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello and welcome TomSjogren,
Basically you need to sort the list of sets like this:

```
media = entry['media']
sorted_media = sorted(media, key=lambda m:m['rank'])
```

I am not familiar with django, but I think it would be like this then:

```
%for m in sorted_media:
    <td valign="top">
    <img width='200' src='{{m['media_link']}}'><br>
    Media Caption: {{m['caption']}}<br>
    Rank: {{m['rank']}}</td>
%end
```

Comment: Worked perfect exactly like you put it. I'm using Bottle not Django but very similar of course. Tnx!!